Sitecore Personalization is not working in chrome
I have set up personalization component for rendering video in rich text. It is not working only in chrome.
The issue is intermittent.
Bases on the dropdown value the video list rich text loaded. Dropdown value is configured in personalization.

If I have 5 videos to play based on the dropdown selection, sometimes it is not loading videos in order as specified in RTE. it is loading videos of default selection. As shown below it is cookie based personalization. Please suggest.


elaborate your issue, in case any logs in console, or app data folder.

Please add more information to this question and request it to be reopened when you have.

@RichardSeal Please reopen my issue still it persists

You really need to take this type of question to a discussion forum like the community forums or the Sitecore Slack channels. SSE is not the right format to diagnose an issue.
